# Compare files in directories with different structures and show differences (20.04)

Tags: backup, rsync, diff, directory-structure

While this may sound like a task that could be accomplished by `rsync`, `diff` and the likes, I haven't managed to succeed.

AFAIK, these tools take the directory structure into account when comparing the files.

As such, if "File A" is located in `~/Dir-A` while "File B" is in `~/Dir-B/Dir-BB`, they will be detected as different files, even though they have the same hash.

The requirements/details are:

- Ubuntu 20.04
- Compare `Dir-A` and `Dir-B`;
- Ignore the location (directory structure) of the files. In other words, I need to check the files only, regardless of the sub-directory they are in (so, in the example above, the files should be considered equal);
- Specify which files are in `Dir-A` and NOT in `Dir-B` (and vice-versa, preferably in different lists/results);
- Both `Dir-A` and `Dir-B` have very different structures. In some specific cases, `Dir-A` is supposed to have everything `Dir-B` has, plus a lot more;
- Bonus: if feasible, it would be nice to be able to check if `Dir-A` has everything from multiple other directories.

To sum it up: my specific situation involves checking multiple backups and copies with very different contents and structures.

In some specific cases, I need to compare a large folder (which is the full backup) with other smaller ones, to check if the backup has everything it should have.

Thanks a lot for your attention.

Comment: For Ubuntu 18.04 LTS at least two good tools exist - [`fslint`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/fslint) and [`komparator`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/komparator).

Comment: You should take the `md5sum`s of each file in the small directory and compare them with the `md5sum`s of each file of the large directory. Some small amount of bash scripting would be sufficient. However, please be aware that you need to calculate the checksums of each and every file in both directories, which may be time consuming.

Comment: Greetings! Sorry, I forgot to mention that I am using Ubuntu 20.04, so fslint is no longer an option. About md5sum: I think it would require too much scripting in the long run. Not to mention that I am not exactly proficient in scripting :<

Comment: Perhaps you can consider the `rdfind` tool?  It will look for duplicates of two directories, regardless of structure.  It will generate a report, so perhaps some of what you need, you will have to find from the report.  You can also make symbolic links, but that's probably not necessary in your case.

Comment: Perhaps this? https://www.linuxuprising.com/2021/03/find-and-remove-duplicate-files-similar.html

Comment: About `rdfind`: not sure if I missed something, but I think it would search for duplicates everywhere, which isn't exactly what I need. I mean, other than comparing the directories, it would also detect duplicates "inside" each of them (e.g. duplicated files in - and only in -`Dir-A`). About `Czkawka`: I will give it a go. Haven't heard of it before. Thanks for the tip

Comment: No luck with `Czkawka`, too (same reason as `rdfind`). Thanks for the recommendation, though: I will surely use it for other purposes. I've been looking for a `fslint` replacement for quite a while, and it just nails it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't really see how to do this without scripting, so here is a short python script to get you started

```py
import hashlib
import os

def get_md5_file(filename, chunk_size=10240):
    ''' Returns md5 sum of the given filename
    '''
    md5_hash = hashlib.md5()
    with open(filename, 'rb') as f:
        while True:
            data = f.read(chunk_size)
            if not data:
                break
            
            md5_hash.update(data)
            
    digest = md5_hash.hexdigest()
    return digest

#print(get_md5('Dir-A/file1.txt'))
#print(get_md5('Dir-B/Dir-B/file1-duplicate.txt'))

def get_md5_dir(root, result=None):
    ''' Returns a dictionary with the md5 sum of every filename in directory root
    '''    
    if result is None:
        result = dict()
    
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(root):
        for filename in files:
            filename = os.path.join(root, filename)
            md5 = get_md5_file(filename)
            if md5 in result:
                print('Warning, duplicate md5 sum', result[md5], filename)
            
            result[md5] = filename
    
    return result

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import argparse

    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Compare directories by md5 sum')
    parser.add_argument('dirA', help='Specify first directory')
    parser.add_argument('dirB', help='Specify one or more directory to compare to',
                        nargs='+')
    args = parser.parse_args()

    # Get md5 sum for each file in dirA and each file in (possibly multiple) dirB
    md5_dirA = get_md5_dir(args.dirA)
    md5_dirB = dict()
    for root in args.dirB:
        get_md5_dir(root, md5_dirB) # update dict in place

    #print(md5_dirA)
    #print(md5_dirB)

    # print files in dirA, but not in dirB
    for md5 in md5_dirA:
        if md5 not in md5_dirB:
            print('%s (%s) not in dirB' % (md5_dirA[md5], md5))

    # print files in dirB, not in dirA
    for md5 in md5_dirB:
        if md5 not in md5_dirA:
            print('%s (%s) not in dirA' % (md5_dirB[md5], md5))
```

To use, save as a text file compare_files_by_hash.py, then, `python3 compare_files_by_hash.py Dir-A Dir-B`.

> Bonus: if feasible, it would be nice to be able to check if Dir-A has everything from multiple other directories.

I am not sure I understood this, but the above allows multiple Dir-B directories, i.e. you can do `python3 compare_files_by_hash.py Dir-A Dir-B Dir-B-2 Dir-B-3` and it will be as if `Dir-B Dir-B-2 Dir-B-3` are all in `Dir-B`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for making that script for me! That was very kind of you. To be honest, I ended up using `Czkawka` with some manual work. However, since I can't select a comment as the accepted answer & due to your effort (which may help other people), the points belong to you!